# Show that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_n$ is absolutely convergent

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Suppose $a_{n}$ is a sequence of positive numbers converging monotically to zero and $b_{n}$ a sequence of real numbers satisfying $\left|b_{n}\right| \leq a_{n}-a_{n+1}$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$. Then show that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_n$ is absolutely convergent.

I am really clueless where to begin with. Is it normal for me to be stuck like this? This is my second semester in analysis but i still cannot figure it out.

Please help me if you could. Any hints will do. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you see how to get an upper bound for $\sum_n |b_n|$?

Comment: For the above hint, if you don't see it, then try writing out what the value of the sum is for the first couple of values of m.

Comment: Since $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left|b_n\right|$ is bounded by $a_{1}$, can I say that the upper bound is $a_{1}$?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** We have $|b_1| \le a_1-a_2$, $|b_2|\le a_2-a_3$, $|b_3|\le a_3-a_4$, $|b_4|\le a_4-a_5$. Let's stop here.

Add up the left hand sides, add up the right-hand sides, and laugh: you are on your way.

Comment: Nicolas how do you know that $|b_n|$  converges? i know it's bounded, but it doesn't guarantee its convergence.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: use the inequality given to bound $\sum_{n=1}^\infty|b_n|$.  Then use the fact that every bounded monotone sequence of real numbers converges.

Comment: Hi, how do you make sure that $|b_n|$ is a monotone sequence? I mean $|b_n|$ can be a constant sequence such that it still satisfies $\left|b_{n}\right| \leq a_{n}-a_{n+1}$ right?

Comment: The sequence of partial sums $(\sum_{n=1}^N |b_n|)_{N=1}^\infty$ is the monotone sequence.